# Unable to apply inline background image with php

Tags: php, escaping

I need to set a background image for the div below. The background image must be assigned as as inline style. I must use php to do this. However, with the way the quotes in html, css inline styles, and php are my method below does not work. I was wondering if someone can help me fix this? Many thanks in advance!

```
$form .= '
    <div class="notes" style="background:url(\'http://i47.tinypic.com/d9897p.png\');" >Hello</div>';
```

Comment: Your code should work. The problem lies elsewhere. -1.

Comment: Do you have height and width dimensions set for this DIV? Each browser renders differently without specified width and height.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$form .= '<div class="notes" style="background:url(http://i47.tinypic.com/dre2cp.png);">Hello</div>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Your inline css is correct. Give a minimum height and width so you can see your image:

```
$form .= '<div class="notes" style="background:url(http://i47.tinypic.com/dre2cp.png); min-height: 400px; min-width: 400px;">Hello</div>';
```

Answer (score 0):

**It may be not working because http://i47.tinypic.com/d9897p.png is a 404-Not Found.**

The below does appear to work, but returns the 404 image.

```
<div style="background-image:url(http://i47.tinypic.com/d9897p.png); min-height:300px; min-width:300px;"> </div>
```

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, they still serve up an image in its place. As such, the OP should expect to see either the correct image, or a 404 image as the background.

Comment: @JonathanSampson It appears you are correct. Some kind of redirect sorcery there. :-) .. Does appear to work with the 404 now that I've tested it properly.

Comment: Not a 404 but a 302 redirect to an image called 404.gif (200 OK).

Answer (score -1):

Avoid printing HTML via PHP strings. Just leave it as is.
there is not a single reason for having `$form` variable.
HTML should be written as it (after closing PHP tag of course)

```
<div class="notes" style="background:url('http://i47.tinypic.com/d9897p.png');" >Hello</div>
```